# How to log custom metadata/context info with each query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm making extensive use of `Entity Framework`, and I need to optimize a lot of DB work.

I see many inefficient queries running in `sys.dm_exec_sessions` etc, but the problem is I don't have much context as to which code is initiating this query.

is there a way in `EF` to add some 'context' to each query, which can be viewed in the `sys.dm_` queries?

pseudo-code:

```
dim d=mydbcontext
d.ContextInfo="Report Window 99"'???
dim results=d.set(of client).ToList
```

And then when I view `SQL Server`s log, I'll see next to each query the 'ContextInfo' that I set.

I see that `SQL Server` has a field `context_info`, but I haven't manage to see it in `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, also I have no idea how to set it via `EF` (and its limited to numeric values)

Thanks so much!

Comment: The best solution I can suggest is using SQL Server Extended Events (so you will be setting up things on the database side and not on the client). They are basically traces you can configure to catch up different connection and query specs. This is a DBA realm so you might want to spend a few minutes reading what they are, how to configure them and how to analyse the results if you are not familiar with them. https://www.brentozar.com/extended-events/

Comment: If extended events for you is a bazooka to kill a fly, you can try encapsulating your SQL code into SPs and using EF to call the SP instead of plain SQL. Then you would just have to review the SP code (this should be the "good practice" way).

Answer (score 0):

heres a very simple way

```
Dim csb = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs)
csb.ApplicationName = "all my logging info..."
```